# How to get column values as rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am looking to do the following task in R. The current table view and expected table view are given below:

- Current Table view:

| Name | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| Name2 | v4 | v5 | v6 |
| Name3 | v7 | v8 | v9 |

- The expected Table view:

| Name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Date 1 | v1 |
| Name1 | Date 2 | v2 |
| Name1 | Date 3 | v3 |
| Name2 | Date 1 | v4 |
| Name2 | Date 2 | v5 |
| Name2 | Date 3 | v6 |
| Name3 | Date 1 | v7 |
| Name3 | Date 2 | v8 |
| Name3 | Date 3 | v9 |

Is there a way to accomplish this task in R. Perhaps using **dplyr** or another method please?

I hope my question is clear

Thank you very much for the help,
Kind Regards,
Deshan

Comment: Name Date Value
Name1 Date 1 v1
Name1 Date 2 v2
Name1 Date 3 v3
Name2 Date 1 v4
Name2 Date 2 v5
Name2 Date 3 v6
Name3 Date 1 v7
Name3 Date 2 v8
Name3 Date 3 v9

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -Name)`